# given an integer array of length n, find tuples $(a,b,c,d)$ such that $d=\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}$

Tags: algorithms

any reference on what kind of problem it is and what algorithm can solve this in $n^2\log n$?

for 5 as d, the numbers 4 and 3 and 0 would work. so i think there should be zero in the array.

maybe use naive approach($O(n^4)$) and memoize the raising to power 2 and adding up the results to decrease the running time?

Comment: Please clarify if you are asking how long to find $n$ non-identical solutions and are permutations of a solution allowed (that is swapping around $a,b,c$ for a given $d$ ) ?  Are arbitrary sets allowed or must they be the lowest possible values of $a,b,c$ ?  Presumably the values must be positive integers or zero, but please state this.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to state the question more carefully.  Don't try to cram it all into one sentence or all into the title.  What is the input to the algorithm?  What is the desired output?  What is the best algorithm you've been able to come up with? What is the context?  Where did you encounter this task?  Can you credit the source, or tell us about the motivation?

Answer (score 0):

You don't memoize "raising to the power of two". Looking up these powers in a table will take ten times longer than just multiplying.

You want $d^2 = a^2 + b^2 + c^2$ or $d^2 - a^2 = b^2 + c^2$.

You take all pairs of two integers x, y in the array and calculate x^2 + y^2 and store that into array A, and calculate x^2 - y^2 where x is the larger number and store that into array B. That takes O(n^2) steps. You want elements in array A and B that have the same value.

Sort both arrays in O (n^2 log n^2) = O (n^2 2 log n) = O (n^2 log n) steps. And then you iterate through both arrays from the start and find equal elements, another O (n^2). Total time O (n^2 log n).